# WPF TemplateBinding Concatenate String for Value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate, templatebinding

I want to add a Custom Property (via a Dependency Property) to my custom ToggleButton Template.
Now i want to have the value of the containing Label (as a placeholder for future implementation) to be a concatenated value of, say "Hello " and the actual Property Value.

Without the concatenation it works fine (displaying "Warrior" on the Label)

But when i try to set the label as a concatenation the xaml doesnt compile anymore.

```
<Label Content="Hello {TemplateBinding local:HeroClassCheckbox.HeroClass}"/>
```

How can i achieve this?

The Rest of the Code:

My .xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="HeroClassCheckbox" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="local:HeroClassCheckbox.HeroClass" Value="NoClass"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Label Content="{TemplateBinding local:HeroClassCheckbox.HeroClass}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton Width="150" Height="50" local:HeroClassCheckbox.HeroClass="Warrior" Style="{DynamicResource HeroClassCheckbox}"/>
</Grid>
```

My .xaml.cs

```
public static class HeroClassCheckbox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeroClassProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HeroClass",
        typeof(string), typeof(HeroClassCheckbox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static string GetHeroClass(UIElement element)
    {
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
        return (string)element.GetValue(HeroClassProperty);
    }
    public static void SetHeroClass(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
        element.SetValue(HeroClassProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a converter as an approach to your goal. Here is an example..

```
    public class HelloLabelConverter : IValueConverter
    {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                    char[] removeThis = "Hello ".ToCharArray();
                    return value.ToString().TrimStart(removeThis);
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                    return string.Format("Hello {0}", value);
            }
    }

   <Window.Resources>
            <local:HelloLabelConverter x:Key="HelloLabelConverter" />
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid>
       <Label Content="{Binding ElementName= lblPropertyToBind, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource HelloLabelConverter}}"></Label>
   </Grid>
```

Comment: that looks like exactly what i was looking for, but unfortunately it throws:
    "The name "HelloLabelConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplication1". WpfApplication1"
which is odd since it clearly does exist. What am i doing wrong here?

[.xaml](http://pastebin.com/Fm7esb4S)

[.xaml.cs](http://pastebin.com/Q8urWFQJ)

Comment: It's hard to figure out that issue when we can't see the structure of your project files. Look for tutorials on how to use value converters and see if it helps

Comment: It is just a standard project (new project->wpf project), but I will look for a Tutorial on value converters.

Comment: @JanOechsler have you made sure that the HelloLabelConverter is inside  the namespace WpfApplication1?